# How to set user who runs command in monit respecting his .bash_profile?

Tags: monit

I want to supervise my Rails application running on unicorn with monit.

Running following two from shell when logged in as root would fail:

- `"/srv/app/current/config/unicorn.sh start"`
- `su -c "/srv/app/current/config/unicorn.sh start" app`

What does work is:

- `su -c "/srv/app/current/config/unicorn.sh start" - app`

It does not suprise me, I'm using [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/) which requires some alterations in `$PATH` which I do in `.bash_profile`.  Unfortunately, I can't make it working with monit.  I've prepared some script which bases on what I found in Internet:

```
check process unicorn
  with pidfile /srv/app/shared/pids/unicorn.pid
  start program = "/srv/app/current/config/unicorn.sh start" as uid app and gid app
  stop program = "/srv/app/current/config/unicorn.sh stop" as uid app and gid app
  group www
```

It looks like `.bash_profile` is not read in this case — how to change it?  Or, alternatively, how to add few directories to `$PATH` which is used by monit?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I've just find out that the best thing to do is to make this `unicorn.sh` with shebang pointing to `/bin/bash` and set `$PATH` in the beginning of script.